# Docker rootless - unable to write to volume

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, fedora

I'm using a Dockerfile with `USER username`, running Docker as rootless:

```
FROM php:8.1.12-fpm-alpine

ARG USER=me
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=$UID

RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "$UID" \
    "$USER"

RUN mkdir -p /data \
    && chown $UID:$UID /data

USER $USER
```

This is my docker compose:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    user: '1000:1000'
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./src:/data
```

For some reason the `/data` permissions are `root:root` instead of the expected `1000:1000` - as used on the host.

I can `chown` the files on the docker container using `chown 1000:1000`, however they end up unreadable for the host.

Is something wrong with my setup? Is this indented?

Thanks

`chown 1000:1000` - unable for the host

Comment: When you say you're running in rootless mode, do you mean that the process within the container is rootless, or the docker daemon itself is rootless?

Comment: @NickODell Both should be rootless. How can you check if this is the case?

Comment: I've followed the instructions given by https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

Comment: `ps aux | grep dockerd` will show you the docker process and what user is running it.

Comment: @NickODell archie  -  0.0  0.0 - - ?       Ssl  16:47   0:00 rootlesskit --net=slirp4netns --mtu=65520 --slirp4netns-sandbox=auto --slirp4netns-seccomp=auto --disable-host-loopback --port-driver=builtin --copy-up=/etc --copy-up=/run --propagation=rslave /usr/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh